# split up classmethods in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am often using classmethods instead of the default constructor in python for example:

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x etc..

    @classmethod
    def from_xml(cls, xml_file):
        x, y, z  = import_something_from_xml(xml_file)
        return cls(x,y,z)
```

this approach works good,
but since i often have large classmethod-constructors I want to split them up in smaller functions. My problem with that is, that these smaller functions can be seen in the Class namespace, Is there any way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark the smaller helper functions as private:

```
@classmethod
def __import_something_from_xml(cls, data):
    #logic
    return a, b, c
```

and you would run:

```
@classmethod
def from_xml(cls, xml_file):
    x, y, z  = cls.__import_something_from_xml(xml_file)
    return cls(x,y,z)
```

Keep in mind this is only naming convention and this method can be accessed from Data namespace.

Or you can designate a helper class:

```
class XMLDataHelper:
    @staticmethod
    def import_something_from_xml(data):
        #logic
        return a, b, c
```

And the code would look like this

```
@classmethod
def from_xml(cls, xml_file):
    x, y, z  = XMLDataHelper.import_something_from_xml(xml_file)
    return cls(x,y,z)
```